# Weird CSS class names

Tags: css

I keep coming across CSS classes such as `.w-asV`, `.w-asK` and `.nH`. Is it some sort of abbreviation or convention or could they have been automatically generating?

Comment: Where are you coming across these?

Comment: Mostly pages by Google and I was wondering if they are abbreviations I could use to tidy my CSS up.

Comment: Google compiles a lot of their pages.  A dev I work with mentioned a lot of their websites are made in java, and compiled to websites, but don't hold me to that.

Comment: This is pure opinion. Who know why google uses these class names

Comment: I'd assume they're compressed/compiled class names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They look like they are generated or minified from a source CSS, but sometimes I use abbreviations like this for class names.

Eg:

```
- mb-s/m/b would be margin-bottom small/medium/big
- fl / fr / cl: float left / right & clear both
```